# Elementary set theory the difference between the two proofs of the distributive law

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, reference-request, proof-writing, terminology

I have come across two different proofs for $(A\cap B)\cup C =(A\cup C) \cap(B \cup C)$. I do not know much about logic, I am just curious if one proof is better than the other. Do these different types of proof have a name in logic/proof theory?

**Proof 1:**
\begin{align}
x \in (A\cap B)\cup C &\Leftrightarrow (x \in A ~~ \text{and}~~ x \in B)~~\text{or}~~ x \in C\tag{1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow  (x \in A ~~ \text{or}~~ x \in C)~~\text{and}~~ (x \in B ~~ \text{or}~~ x \in C)\tag{2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow x \in (A\cup C) \cap(B \cup C)\tag{3}
\end{align}

My problem with this proof is that it seems we simply swap $\cup$ to "or" and $\cap$ to "and" with no formal definition and also from step (1) to (2) we provide no proof.

**Proof 2:**

We know:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
 (A\cap B)\cup C \subset (A \cup C)
\end{equation}

Also:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
 (A\cap B)\cup C \subset (B \cup C)
\end{equation}

Hence,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
 (A\cap B)\cup C \subset (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) 
\end{equation}

We can also show  ($A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) \subset (A\cap B)\cup C$. Consequently, $(A\cap B)\cup C =(A\cup C) \cap(B \cup C)$.

Although each statement in the second proof also needs to be proven, all the proofs rely entirely on the definitions of set, membership of a set, and subsets (everything is defined based on set and set definitions as opposed to **Proof 1**, which I think is using the equivalency between set union and intersections with logical 'and' and 'or').

Is there a formal distinction between these two proofs in logic/proof theory?

I am very much interested in these sort of questions, is there any reference I can read so I can educate myself better in this topic?

Comment: In the books that I have read, such as Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", proofs were given in the format of Proof 2. Not sure about other books though.

Comment: Remember that $\cup$ means "or" and $\cap$ means "and." From there it follows using propositional logic.

Comment: The laws of logic imply that $\lor$ & $\land$ are distributive over each other. That justifies (2) from (1) in the 1st proof.

Comment: In both proofs, you are expected to know the definitions of $A\cap B$ and $A \cup B$. Thus the first proof makes use of those definitions in step (1) without comment. You seem okay with this in the second proof, so I am a bit bewildered that you are bothered by it in the first. As DanielWainfleet says, step (2) of the second proof is the distributivity of "or" over "and", which is something it expects you to know. Assuming that law had already been proven in the source for this proof, it is acceptable.

Comment: Even though the first proof makes use of a logical result, I would rate it as the more elementary proof, as it shows all the steps: A *direct* application of the definitions of $\cap$ and $\cup$, followed by the distributivity of "or" over "and" (which is one step, assuming it had been proven previously), and finishing with another direct application of the definitions of $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Comment: I understand the definition of $A \cap B$ in the second proof because it has a definition, i.e., ($\forall x \in A, x \in B \rightarrow A \subset B). But for the first proof, what is that missing comment in step (1) that defines set operators in terms of logical operators? Don't we need to prove the equivalency of set and logical operators?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet don't we need to prove equivalency between $\cap$ and $\cup$ (set operators) and $\land$ and $\wedge$ (logical operators)? Also don't logical operators operate on variables?[linline Link] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Values- do we need to prove they operate on sets too?

Comment: $\land$ and $\lor$ operate on propositions. Let $P, Q, R$ be $x\in A, x\in B, x\in C$ respectively. Then $[(P\land Q)\lor R]\iff [(P\lor R)\land (Q\lor R)].$ This question is not about Boolean algebra.